# Django Rest - Redirect Password Form?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-allauth

I recently upgraded to Django 4.0 and upgraded `django-allauth` with alongside `django-rest-auth`.

When a user fills out the password reset form under `http://localhost:8000/api/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/` they get a link in the console that goes to:
`http://localhost:8000/users/reset/2n/bxggn2-05019c81f9d6dfda6a10b7cfec09e839/`

[image]

[image]

The link provided gets me to this old form:

[image]

How can I get this message in the console to point to `accounts/password/reset/key/1-set-password/`?

That form looks like this:

[image]

That’s where my `allauth` form lives and I’m not fully sure if this is the correct approach.

Below is some of my settings and urls.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Local,
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'users',

    # 3rd Party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
    'drf_yasg',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ],
      'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView, EmailVerificationSentView 

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls')),

    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),

    path('api/dj-rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/<str:key>/',
         ConfirmEmailView.as_view()), # Needs to be defined before the registration path

    path('api/dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api/dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),

    path('api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', 
         EmailVerificationSentView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),

    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),


]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out!

Had to update my `urls.py` to the following:

```
from dj_rest_auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView

path('users/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view()),
```

This url now points to the django password reset confirm view in the django rest API which is fine to reset the password on the backend.

Thanks!